# Group the map values to avoid duplicate

Tags: java, collections

I have a Map(map1) whose key is another map(map2) and value is string.

The value of map1 has several duplicate, so I must group them and set as key in another map3 whose value has to be map2.

```
eg:

map1 {  [[a,b],xyz],  [[c,d],wrt] , [[e,f],xyz] , [[r,m],xyz]  }


output should be :

map3 {  [ xyz,[ [a,b],[e,f],[r,m] ] ]  , [ wrt,[ [c,d] ]
```

can i obtain like this ?

Comment: You can convert the first map to a set and combine it with map2 for map3.

Comment: what you're aiming is to reverse `key` with `value` so if map1 is `Map<K,V>` you want to get `Map<V,K>` from that

Comment: map1 it seems a list, I think you should formulate more clearly your question.

Comment: should "map3 {  [ xyz,[ [a,b],[e,f],[r,m] ] ]  , [ wrt,[ [c,d] ]" not read "
map2 {  [ xyz,[ [a,b],[e,f],[r,m] ] ]  , [ wrt,[ [c,d] ]" ? Typo ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try MultiValueMap from (commons-collections) library

```
Map map1 = new HashMap<String[], String>();
map1.put(new String[]{"a", "b"}, "xyz");
map1.put(new String[]{"c", "d"}, "wrt");
map1.put(new String[]{"e", "f"}, "xyz");
map1.put(new String[]{"c", "d"}, "xyz");

MultiValueMap map2 = new MultiValueMap();
for(String[] key: map1.keySet()) {
    String value = map1.get(key);
    map2.add(value, key);
}
// now you got map2 as you want
```

Comment: I don't see the relevance for MultiValueMap to OP's situation

Comment: updated for detail codes

Comment: now I see the relevance :)

Answer (score 0):

NO, Though you can declare it but while using it, it may allow same keys(human readable). Because `Map` do not override `Object`'s equals method your key comparison will be on JVM's object level (it may be different for objects with same values in them).

Comment: `Map` is an interface so why should it overwrite `equals`. BTW: `AbstractMap` overwrites `equals` and most (or all?) implementations of `java.util` extending this class.

Comment: here `Map` is ( I thought obvious ) a solid implementation of `Map` interface. And you will not create another implementation of `Map` so you will not be able to edit the previous JAVA provided implementations for overriding `equals`. This is the reason answer is **NO**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the stream API to solve it:

```
Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>> map3 = map.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entry::getValue,
                                   Collectors.mapping(Entry::getKey,
                                                      Collectors.toList())));
```

Explanation:
The entries will be grouped by its values (`groupingBy(Entry::getValue`).
But the values should not be a list of entries so the *downstream* is necessary. This is the list of keys of the original map.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your post what do you mean by `map2`, but let's assume you would like to use each `Map.Entry<String, String> entry` from `map2` for each key for `map1`.

The following code is Java 7, it's a bit verbose. It could be done shorter with Java 8 streams, I guess.

```
public class MapReverser {

    private Map<Map.Entry<String, String>, String> map1 = new HashMap<>();

    private Map<String, String> map2 = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    private void prepareMaps() {
        map2.put("a", "b");
        map2.put("c", "d");
        map2.put("e", "f");
        map2.put("r", "m");

        String[] valueArray = { "xyz", "wrt", "xyz", "xyz" };
        int i = 0;
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map2.entrySet()) {
            map1.put(entry, valueArray[i]);
            i++;
        }
    }

    public Map<String, List<Map.Entry<String, String>>> reverse() {
        Map<String, List<Map.Entry<String, String>>> reversedMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (Map.Entry<Map.Entry<String, String>, String> entry : map1.entrySet()) {
            List<Map.Entry<String, String>> reversedMapValue = reversedMap.get(entry.getValue());
            if (reversedMapValue == null) {
                reversedMapValue = new ArrayList<>();
            }
            reversedMapValue.add(entry.getKey());
            reversedMap.put(entry.getValue(), reversedMapValue);
        }
        return reversedMap;
    }

    private void printResult(Map<String, List<Map.Entry<String, String>>> reversedMap) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, List<Map.Entry<String, String>>> entry : reversedMap.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("Key: \n" + entry.getKey());
            System.out.println("Values:");
            List<Map.Entry<String, String>> valuesList = entry.getValue();
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> value : valuesList) {
                System.out.println(value );
            }
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MapReverser mapReverser = new MapReverser();
        mapReverser.prepareMaps();
        Map<String, List<Map.Entry<String, String>>> reversedMap = mapReverser.reverse();
        mapReverser.printResult(reversedMap);
    }
}
```